# Prove that $Hom_{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z, \mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z/(n,m)\mathbb Z. $

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I already proved this:

By Problem $4$ (on pg.$350$), we know that $Hom_{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z, A) \cong A_n$ where $A_n = \{ a \in A| na = 0\}$(i.e., $A_n$ is the annihilator in $A$ of the ideal $(n)$ of $\mathbb Z.$) and $A$ is any $\mathbb Z$-module, $a$ is any element of $A$ and $n$ a positive integer.

But I do not know how to complete my proof (I want a simple proof without using exact sequences ), any help about this please?

**Note that:**

I do not know if this will help me to reach a simple proof but I already proved that   $$ \mathbb Z_m \otimes_Z \mathbb Z_n \cong \mathbb Z/d\mathbb Z,$$where $d$ is the $g.c.d$ of the integers $m$ and $n.$

Comment: You can set $A:=\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$ and see what $A_n$ equals.

Comment: it is $x \in \mathbb Z_m$ such that $nx = 0$ but also $x$ must satisfy that $mx = 0$ but then what @Dave? How can I complete my solution?

Comment: So use Bezout's lemma to conclude that $(m,n)x=0$

Comment: The equation $nx=0$ is holding in $\mathbb Z_m$. Now lift this to $\mathbb Z$: $m\mid nx$.